# Object of type User is not JSON serializable type error at </urlpath>

Tags: python, json, serializable

I'm running a website using Django and I got this error

Here is models.py

```
PASSWORD_REGEX = re.compile(r"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$")

class UserManager(models.Manager):            
    def authenticate(self, email, password):
        users = self.filter(email=email)
        if not users:
            return False
        user = users[0]
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode(), user.password.encode())
    def register(self, form):
        pw = bcrypt.hashpw(form['pass2'].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()
        return self.create(
            first_name = form['name'],
            last_name = form['lastname'],
            email = form['email'],
            city = form['city'],
            state = form['state'],
            password = pw,
        )


class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = UserManager()
```

and views.py

```
def index(request):
    if "user_id" in request.session :
        return redirect("/dashboard")
    return render(request, "login.html")


def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        new_user = User.objects.register(request.POST)
        messages.success(request, "You have successfully registered!")
        return redirect('/')


def login(request):
    if not User.objects.authenticate(request.POST['email'], request.POST['password2']):
        # messages.error(request, 'Invalid Email/Password')
        return redirect('/')
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
    request.session['user_id'] = user.id
    request.session['user'] = user
    # messages.success(request, "You have successfully logged in!")
    return redirect('/dashboard')
```

Comment: What is your exact question? What type of debugging have you done already?

Comment: Please fix the layout of your question, so it's easier to read. Take some time to learn how the StackOverflow editor works (e.g., the triple quotes are unnecessary, and, in fact, incorrect, given that it's Python code). Thank you.